# MongoDB - Add elements to sub array that meets the filter condition

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Here is an example : [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9sfCAsNcq3_)

I am trying to add 'X' and 'Y' only to the `subcategory` arrays that contains `EDUCATION` key. What is happening here is that it adds 'X' and 'Y' to all `subcategory` if at least on of them contains the `EDUCATION` key.

Comment: your playground link is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use arrayFilters, to match specific element in an array.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$push": {
    "data.category.$[elem].subcategory": {
      "$each": [
        "X",
        "Y"
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.subcategory": "EDUCATION"
    }
  ]
})
```

Check this [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7LeaWgBv1ea)

Comment: Doesnt work sir

Comment: It only adds to the docs, whose subcategory contains `EDUCATION` isn't it expected? Can you paste the expected output in the question

Comment: this only adds to the first subcategory list. if you add $[] it will fail again

Comment: Thnx sir ;) ---